# Hadoop 2.2.0 is compatible with Mahout 0.8?

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I have hadoop cluster version 2.2.0 running with mahout 0.8, is it compatible? Because whenever I run this command:

```
bin/mahout recommenditembased --input mydata.dat --usersFile user.dat --numRecommendations 2 --output output/ --similarityClassname SIMILARITY_PEARSON_CORRELATION
```

Give me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
at org.apache.mahout.common.HadoopUtil.getCustomJobName(HadoopUtil.java:174)
at org.apache.mahout.common.AbstractJob.prepareJob(AbstractJob.java:614)
at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.preparation.PreparePreferenceMatrixJob.run(PreparePreferenceMatrixJob.java:75)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob.run(RecommenderJob.java:158)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob.main(RecommenderJob.java:312)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:72)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:152)
at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:194)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

Or Im wrong? Any info would be helpful.

Comment: compiling 0.8 against 2.2 has problems the last time i tried. you should use 1.2.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not work with Hadoop 2.x, [someone else got the same error message like you](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/mahout-user/201309.mbox/%3CCAEccTyyOapUzdBxxKr1YtBZPdgSxk_RTK-ASrM5UwmCZsDhozA@mail.gmail.com%3E).

It seems that [at the very least it would require a recompile](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/mahout-user/201308.mbox/%3CCAEccTyx3F7J5yF8G6wyb+X5tBDfaZS9xsyj1E-Ym52bgTgwJSA@mail.gmail.com%3E).

And more people are having the same problems: [how can I compile/using mahout for hadoop 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767843/how-can-i-compile-using-mahout-for-hadoop-2-0)

Comment: Good to know, Ive searched too on apache mail list, some people had this problem too.

Answer (score 3):

About an hour ago Mahout has officially added support to Hadoop 2.x in the master branch (see [MAHOUT-1329](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-1329))

Checkout the code here https://github.com/apache/mahout and recompile using:

```
mvn clean package -Dhadoop2.version=2.2.0
```

Try and see if that works.

Comment: It gives error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver([Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:195)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)

Comment: @Imran did u apply the patch for Mahout-1329 before trying to recompile? Better if you could try running with Mahout HEAD.

Comment: I've just recompiled the code of trunk using maven goal..

how to apply patch ???

Answer (score 0):

You can get the source code from `github` https://github.com/apache/mahout and run the following command

```
mvn -Dhadoop2.version=2.2.0 -DskipTests clean install
```

Then, you can find the release package in `distribution/target/`