# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError in mahout 0.9 & hadoop 2.6

Tags: macos, hadoop, mahout

Iam trying to run random forest example. The command that I run is

```
hadoop jar mahout-examples-0.9-job.jar org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce.BuildForest -Dmapred.max.split.size=1874231 -d testdata/KDDTrain+.arff -ds testdata/KDDTrain.info -sl 5 -p -t 100 -o nsl-forest
```

I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
at org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce.partial.PartialBuilder.processOutput(PartialBuilder.java:113)
at org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce.partial.PartialBuilder.parseOutput(PartialBuilder.java:89)
at org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce.Builder.build(Builder.java:294)
at org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce.BuildForest.buildForest(BuildForest.java:228)
at org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce.BuildForest.run(BuildForest.java:188)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce.BuildForest.main(BuildForest.java:252)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

I use Mahout 0.9 and Hadoop 2.6.0

What I need to do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error is typical using some jars that are compiled on Hadoop-1 and are being used with Hadoop-2

I am pointing some urls please go through them.

[Mahout 0.9 and Hadoop 2.2.0 - Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702947/mahout-0-9-and-hadoop-2-2-0-found-interface-org-apache-hadoop-mapreduce-jobcon)

[Hadoop 2.2.0 is compatible with Mahout 0.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911821/hadoop-2-2-0-is-compatible-with-mahout-0-8)

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.mahout.user/20328

Comment: thanks for your help. it is working now by applying the steps in this link http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.mahout.user/20333